# Allow linking to duplicates on other Stack Exchange sites for popular closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I've come across a few popular, useful questions on Stack Overflow that have been closed as off-topic, which have duplicates on other sites. For examples, Stack 
Overflow question *[Is it possible to make a Bash file run as root in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015485)* is closed, with a banner that suggests seeking help on Server Fault:

> "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault." – Duncan, Brian Clozel, Trinimon, Bhavik Ambani, AlSki

But there's already an open duplicate on another Stack Exchange site where the question is on-topic, *[How to run a cron job using the sudo command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924)*.

It would be nice if, rather than just closing the Stack Overflow question, somebody - even if the power was only available to moderators - could also mark it as a duplicate of the question on *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*. (The text of the duplicate banner might need to be slightly different from normal.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Doesn't address *closed* questions at all. The extent of Shog's answer there is 'on topic cross-site dupes should remain open; if the dupe is off-topic on one site, it should be closed and perhaps migrated.' The situation my question is about (what to do with dupes *after* they have been closed on sites where they're off-topic) isn't touched on.

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Basically, I'm asking about what to do with off-topic questions *that have already been closed* and have on-topic dupes on other sites. The discussion you linked to never explored beyond the point of closing them, so my question doesn't overlap with it - I think.

Comment: The discussion had not gone anywhere much, really. But I sorta see your point.

Comment: I like the idea, but my only hesitation is that it might be slightly encouraging people to ask questions without double-checking whether they'd fit on other stackExchange sites..? not sure if that makes sense

Comment: You can still leave a comment with a link to the dupe, whether it's closed or not. The link won't be all bannerized, but it will still be there for future users.